# Why does Symfony debug:messenger command show my messenger handler twice when I use AsMessageHandler attribute?

Tags: php, symfony, php-8, symfony-messenger

My Symfony 6.2 bundle has an handler like the following

```php
use Symfony\Component\Messenger\Attribute\AsMessageHandler;

#[AsMessageHandler]
class MyHandler {
    public function __invoke(MyMessage $message): void {
    }
}
```

When I run the `bin/command debug:messenger` command I got this output, with the handled part shown twice

```
  MyMessage                                            
      handled by MyHandler
      handled by MyHandler
```

Instead, when I use the deprecated method of implementing the MessageHandlerInterface instead of the attribute as follow, the debug command correctly shows only one handled row

```php
use Symfony\Component\Messenger\Handler\MessageHandlerInterface;

class MyHandler implements MessageHandlerInterface {
    public function __invoke(MyMessage $message): void {
    }
}
```

I am expecting the attribute version to show one handler like the deprecated version.

Answer (score 0):

The behavior you are observing is not a bug or error. The `#[AsMessageHandler]` attribute reflects the internal wiring of messenger handlers in Symfony 5.3 and later.

For detailed docs have a look at this [Link](https://symfony.com/doc/current/messenger.html)